# Portfolio Allocation given Sharpe Ratio

Tags: portfolio-optimization, sharpe-ratio, diversification

If there are two portfolios with sharpe ratios of 1.2 and 0.5, what would be the allocation rationale.

If the correlation between portfolios is:

$a. 0 $

$b. 0.8 $

$c.-0.8 $

I see there is a diversification benefit in the c case, but is there a way to decide weights without more information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimal Sharpe you can achieve, by the Markowitz portfolio, is
$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-\rho^2} \left( 1.2^2 - 2 \rho (1.2) (0.5) + 0.5^2 \right)}.
$$
The optimal portfolio is
$$
\frac{1}{1-\rho^2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -\rho \\
-\rho & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1.2\\ 0.5
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $\rho$ is the correlation of the assets.

You can do the rest of the math.

Comment: Looks reasonable, but where do these equations come from?

Comment: Rescale the assets to unit risk. Their returns are then their Sharpe ratios, and their covariance is the correlation matrix, with 1 on the diagonal and $\rho$ on the off diagonal. If you invert that covariance matrix you get the $1 / (1-\rho^2)$ times the matrix term. So the lower equation is just $\Sigma^{-1} \mu$ on the rescaled returns. The units are 'risk units'; a real portfolio would be positively rescaled to the desired risk level. The top equation is simply $\sqrt{\mu^{\top} \Sigma^{-1}\mu}$.

Comment: BTW, you can confirm that the minimum optimal Sharpe is achieved when $\rho = 0.5/1.2$, in which case the optimal Sharpe is 1.2, _i.e._ there is _zero_ diversification benefit.